# Is there an easy way to express Integers with an arbitrary base in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, erlang, integer

Erlang has a very nice syntax for expressing integers with an arbitrary base. It's `base#number`.

Example:

```
> 2#101010.
42
> 16#2A.
42
```

Is there something similar in Ruby?
I already know of [`#to_i(base=10)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a nice
[list](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Numerics)
of possible literals, but it basically boils down to

```
10 # base 10 by default
0b1010 # base 2
012 # base 8
0xa # base 16
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple, though not terribly efficient or safe way to do this for arbitrary bases:

```
class Fixnum
  def as_base(b)
    to_s.to_i(b)
  end
end

101010.as_base(2)
42
```

(And you would have to do the same for `class Bignum` to work for arbitrarily large integer literals...)

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the syntax other than the C-inspired `0x` notation for hex numbers, `0b` for binary, or leading `0` for octal. `to_i` works quite well in practice though.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an int, you can express it in any base with to_s, much like to_i on a string.

```
irb(main):013:0> puts 255.to_s(2)
11111111
```